# matplotlib separate ticks from spine

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-3.5

Is there a way to define a distance between the ticks and the spine on a line plot? I have managed to create the following (yticks are separated from the spine and the grid lines)

[image]

With the following code:

```
params_1 = {
          'axes.spines.top': False,
          'axes.spines.left': False,
          'axes.spines.right': False,
          'ytick.major.size': 10,
         }
plt.rcParams.update(params_1)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(13,6.5))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, facecolor='w')
ax.set_ylim([5,15])
ax.set_xticks([5,10,15,20,25])
ax.yaxis.grid()
ax_xgrid = ax.xaxis.grid(linestyle=':', linewidth=1.5)
[i.set_marker('o') for i in ax.yaxis.get_ticklines()]
[i.set_markeredgecolor('w') for i in ax.yaxis.get_ticklines()]
[i.set_markeredgewidth(4) for i in ax.yaxis.get_ticklines()]
```

This looks is exactly what I would like but if is save the figure with transparency then I see the white circles around the yticks. Any ideas how to solve this?

Thanks,

Comment: Can you show a [mcve] of the code that produces the chart, such that people can easily change it to answer this question?

Comment: I have edited the question. Hope is clearer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you are asking, this can be easily done using [the `tick_params()` helper function](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params.html?highlight=matplotlib%20axes%20axes%20tick_params#matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params).

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
ax.tick_params(axis='y', color='none', pad=50)
ax.grid()
plt.show()
```

[image]

**EDIT** I did not understand what you were trying to do. What you want to increase the distance between the left axis and the main part of the plot. To do so, use [the Spine.set_position() function](https://matplotlib.org/api/spines_api.html#matplotlib.spines.Spine.set_position). The following should work:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['left'].set_position(('outward', 20))
[i.set_marker('o') for i in ax.yaxis.get_ticklines()]
ax.grid()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: The pad parameter if I understand correctly defines the distance between the labels and the ticks. I would like to change the distance between the ticks and the spine/grid. I have edited my question to make it a bit clearer.

Comment: Ok, your edits helped me understand what you were trying to achieve. I've edited my answer accordingly

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thanks